Child class's attribute did not override which was defined in parent class
I have a parent and two child classes defined like this
import pygame
class Person():
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load('person.png').convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, 
                                            (int(self.image.get_width() * 0.5), 
                                             int(self.image.get_height() * 0.5)))
        print('size: ', self.image.get_size())

class Teacher(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('teacher.png').convert_alpha()
        
class Doctor(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('doctor.png').convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, 
                                            (int(self.image.get_width() * 1.2), 
                                             int(self.image.get_height() * 0.75)))
...

The size of the picture of person.png, teacher.png and doctor.png is 98x106, 125x173 and 97x178 respectively.
When I run the following code, its output confused me. It seemed the code pygame.image.load() and pygame.transform.scale() in the child classes Teacher and Doctor didn't override the attribute defined in the parent class Person.
pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
players =  {'Teacher': Teacher(), 'Doctor': Doctor()}
Output:
pygame 2.4.0 (SDL 2.26.4, Python 3.10.9)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
size:  (49, 53) <---- expected to be (62, 86)
size:  (49, 53) <---- expected to be (116, 133)

What happened? What did I do wrong?

print(players['Teacher'].image.get_size()) will give you the expected output.

Why would you load an image during __init__ of Person and then load another image if you instantiate Teacher or Doctor?

Because I had no idea how to write a logical code (awkward smile)!

It's a matter of the order how everything is executed:
In the subclasses, you call the super-constructor (super().__init__()), which still will load the picture person.png and output the size. Only afterwards the code in the constructors of the subclasses will be executed. So after the construction, the image property should be set correctly, but at the moment of the printout it is not.
You could for example solve it, by having a file-name argument in the super constructor to which you hand the file names, fitting for the sub classes.
Similarly, you should proceed with the scaling:
class Person():
    def __init__(self, filename='person.png', x_scale=0.5, y_scale=0.5):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, 
                                            (int(self.image.get_width() * x_scale), 
                                             int(self.image.get_height() * y_scale)))
        print('size: ', self.image.get_size())

class Teacher(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('teacher.png', 1.0, 1.0)
        
class Doctor(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('doctor.png', 1.2, 0.75)


Thanks, Christian. That means it would be more Pythonic if I don't have any code in the constructor of the Person class, just like this def __init__: pass then simply have the pygame.image.load and pygame.transform.scale in each of the Teacher and Doctor?

Hi Nemo , I don't know exactly about the best pythonic way, there probably somebody else can give you a better answer. Personally, I try to avoid duplications if it doesn't mean too much of a hassle, so having this in the super constructor would be fine for me. I don't know whether you have seen it, but I added some change to my answer, accounting for the scaling as well.

With the scaling I'm just not so sure about the Teacher, because your expected value does not add up for me. According to the text, the original file should be 134x179 and you expect the result to be 62, 86, but that would be a factor of ~0.46?/~0.48

Very observant you are! I made a mistake and have now rectified the size of teacher.png in the OP.

You will find the "lazy" approach to loading and transforming the images more efficient. It also provides (IMHO) a better overall OO pattern.
Consider this:
import pygame


class Person:
    def __init__(self, x_scale=0.5, y_scale=0.5, png="person.png"):
        self._png = png
        self._image = None
        self._x_scale = x_scale
        self._y_scale = y_scale

    @property
    def png(self):
        return self._png
    
    @property
    def x_scale(self):
        return self._x_scale

    @property
    def y_scale(self):
        return self._y_scale

    @property
    def image(self):
        if self._image is None:
            temp = pygame.image.load(self.png).convert_alpha()
            self._image = pygame.transform.scale(
                temp,
                (
                    int(temp.get_width() * self.x_scale),
                    int(temp.get_height() * self.y_scale),
                ),
            )
        return self._image

    def size(self):
        return self.image.get_size()

class Teacher(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(1.0, 1.0, "teacher.png")

class Doctor(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(1.2, 0.75, "doctor.png")

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), 0, 32)

print(Doctor().size())

Note that the relevant image is not loaded / transformed during __init__
All we do is make a note of the png filename. Then, later, when we need to access the image we do this via a property

I'm sure this is a great answer but it's above my level at the moment. Thanks for all the technical details that give me pointer to what I should learn/read next to improve my Python skill.

The issue comes from the print statement being inside of the Person class. When you are initializing the Teacher and the Doctor, the first thing they do is initialize the parent class Person. The parent class is setting the image to the person.png image, then cutting it's dimensions in half. Then it is immediately printing the size right there. This is why the sizes being printed are half the size of the original person.png file. The init methods of the child classes Teacher and Doctor are called after the init method of Person, which means you aren't updating the images until after the print statements are called. You need to take the print statement and remove it from the Person class, then place it at the end of the Teacher and Doctor init methods. It should look like this:
class Person():
def __init__(self):
    self.image = pygame.image.load('person.png').convert_alpha()
    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, 
                                        (int(self.image.get_width() * 0.5), 
                                         int(self.image.get_height() * 0.5)))

class Teacher(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('teacher.png').convert_alpha()
        print('size: ', self.image.get_size())

class Doctor(Person):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load('doctor.png').convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, 
                                        (int(self.image.get_width() * 1.2), 
                                         int(self.image.get_height() * 0.75)))
        print('size: ', self.image.get_size())

